# Oracle - How to pass a parameter from batch file to SQL file which contains a PL/SQL procedure

Tags: sql, oracle, batch-file, plsql

I written a command in batch file which calls a .sql file which contains a pl/sql procedure. But I need to set the a parameter in PL/SQL procedure which common throughout the procedure from the batch file.

The batch file is as below.

```
set parameterOne=%1
set parameterTwo=%2


sqlplus -s uid/pwd filepath/filename.sql %parameterOne %parameterTwo
```

And the PL/SQL procedure in .sql file is as follow.

```
DECLARE parameterOneValue       INT;
        parameterTwoValue       INT;
BEGIN

parameterOneValue := $(parameterOne);
parameterTwoValue := $(parameterTwo);

//procedure block

END;
```

I need to set the `parameterOne`, `parameterTwo` attribute from batch file to `parameterOneValue`, `parameterTwoValue` in .sql files respectively. Could anyone provide solution to this?

Comment: `sqlplus ... %parameterOne %parameterTwo` should be changed to `sqlplus ... %parameterOne% %parameterTwo%`

Answer (score 0):

Use **SET DEFINE ON**, and use `&` for variable substitution.

For example,

Your batch file:

```
set parameterOne=%1
set parameterTwo=%2    

sqlplus -s uid/pwd filepath/filename.sql %parameterOne %parameterTwo
```

SQL*Plus substitution in PL/SQL block:

```
parameterOneValue := &1;
parameterTwoValue := &2;
```

`&` will substitute the actual value that you set in the batch file.

Comment: Thank you for the input but this doesn't seen to be working. I getting the following error.                                                                                         
  " Enter value for orgid: 
     [exec] SP2-0546: User requested Interrupt or EOF detected. "

Comment: It should be `&1` and `&2`. SQL*Plus accepts parameters positionally.

Comment: @Ben Ah yes, it was copy paste. Thanks for the correction.

Comment: @Nancy Please make the correction as suggested by Ben, I had a typo originally.